# Parse XML using Nokogiri but unable to resolve namespaces

Tags: ruby, xml, curl, nokogiri

I have an XML message and my script needs to be able to parse the "AccountStatus" node element. My script works correctly if the XML posted without namespaces.

When I included the original namespaces, a large chunk of XML data will be missing when the script executes `Nokogiri::XML(request.body.read)`.

Here is the XML sample:

```
curl -i -H -X POST -d "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <EnvelopeStatus>
        <RecipientStatuses>
            <RecipientStatus>
                <Type>Signer</Type>
                <CustomFields />
                <AccountStatus>Active</AccountStatus>
                <RecipientId>ab2bf57b-72b7-48e7-8298-b1c7b56930b9</RecipientId>
            </RecipientStatus>
        </RecipientStatuses>
    </EnvelopeStatus>
</DocuSignEnvelopeInformation>" localhost:4567/shunt?uri=http://requestb.in/1hiag0y1
```

Here is my script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'uri'
require 'nokogiri'
#require 'pry'
#require 'pp'

post '/shunt' do
puts "hello world"

xmldoc = Nokogiri::XML(request.body.read)
puts xmldoc

xmldoc.xpath("//docu:DocuSignEnvelopeInformation/EnvelopeStatus/RecipientStatuses/RecipientStatus", "docu"=>"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema").each do |node|
    puts node.text
end
end
```

Here is the output:

```
hello world
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DocuSignEnvelopeInformation/>
```

Comment: Thank you 7stud. Yes I messed up with the double quotes with the quotes in the XML message. After using the single quotes, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 2):

#### curl problems:

It looks like the first issue you are having is with your curl command.  Note, your curl command specifies a `-H` option, yet doesn't specify a header. And if I try to run your curl command I get an error:

```
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'POST'
```

It looks like the quotes are messing up your command.  In this curl command:

```
curl -i -X POST -d "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> ...
```

...the first quoted string is:

```
"<?xml version="
```

And then how curl interprets everything after that--who knows.  You can cure that problem by using single quotes around the exterior of the xml.  But, it's much easier to put the xml in a file, then have curl read the file.  If you use the `-d` option with an `@`, like this:

```
 -d @file_name
```

curl will read the xml from the file whose name is file_name.  Here's an example:

```
curl -i -X POST -d @./xml_files/xml5.xml http://localhost:4567/shunt
```

#### nokogiri problems:

Every child tag in your xml is part of the *default* namespace; therefore each child tag name is preceded by the namespace name.  Yet, you only put `docu:` in front of the first tag in your xpath:

```
//docu:DocuSignEnvelopeInformation/EnvelopeStatus/....
                                   ^
                                   |
                         missing namespace name
```

`docu:` has to precede *every* tag name.  Also, note that instead of specifying the `docu` namespace, you can just use `xmlns:` in front of every tag in your xpath.   And, it's much simpler to just write:

```
  xpath = '//xmlns:AccountStatus'
```

> The vendor sent me a XML message

The details of how that is going to be done are important.

Here is a curl command that will do a *file upload*:

```
curl -i -F "xmlfile=@xml5.xml" http://localhost:4567/shunt
```

`-F` means POST a *file upload*. Locally, the xml is in a file called xml5.xml.  Then, your sinatra app can do this:

```
post '/shunt' do
  require 'nokogiri'

  doc = Nokogiri::XML(
    params['xmlfile'][:tempfile].read
  )

  xpath = '//xmlns:AccountStatus'
  target_tag = doc.at_xpath(xpath)
  puts target_tag.text
end
```

Or, with this curl command:

```
curl -i -X POST -d @xml5.xml http://localhost:4567/shunt
```

...your route would look like this:

```
post '/shunt' do
  require 'nokogiri'

  doc = Nokogiri::XML(
    request.body.read
  )

  xpath = '//xmlns:AccountStatus'
  target_tag = doc.at_xpath(xpath)
  puts target_tag.text
end
```

#### Content-Type headers:

The `-d` option sets the Content-Type header in the request to:

> This will cause  curl  to  pass  the data to the server using the  content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

The `-F` option sets the Content-Type header in the request to:

> This causes curl to POST data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data